# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null upload file PDF

Tags: laravel, pdf

i want to upload pdf FILE with laravel,,, in my controller :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $categories = Category::findOrFail($request->category_id);
    $request->request->add(['code' => $categories->aliases]);
    $request->validate([
        'code' => 'string',
        'pdf' => 'required',
        'eur' => 'required|numeric',
        'date' => 'required'
    ]);
```

`

```
enter code here`$rawInput = $request->except('image');
    $priceInput = $request->only(['idr', 'usd', 'eur', 'date']);
    $pdf = $request->file('pdf')->getClientOriginalName();
```

in my blade...

```
 <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">PDF</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="file" name="pdf" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('pdf') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}">

                @if ($errors->has('pdf'))
                  <span class="invalid-feedback">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('pdf') }}</strong>
                  </span>
                @endif
              </div>
            </div>
```

when i click upload,,, error like this

```
i am getting error undefined varibale $pdf.. $pdf variable i PUT and compact in 

return view('inventory::raws.show', compact(['raw', 'pdf']));
```

..
whats wrong my code........

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$pdf = $request->file('pdf')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: thanks,, but when i return view to show.blade.php error undefined variable pdf..

this my return view  return view('inventory::raws.show', compact(['raw', 'pdf']));